# Check if a list of objects contains another list (only have a property) in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two Lists:

One list from database that contains objects -> SystemList

```
public class MyObject
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

One list from the user that contains ids from objects ->  UserList

```
List<short> UserList;
```

I want to write in linq a query that check if all the items from the UserList are in the SystemList

I solved this temporally using this:

```
bool hasAllItems = true;
foreach (var g in UserList) {
    hasAllItems = hasAllItems && SystemList.Any(a => a.Id == g);
}
```

I know this can be improved.

Comment: I fully support you in your endeavours.

Comment: You really need to provide some more detail if you want to get a decent answer

Comment: It would be something like `UserList.Except(SystemList).Any()` but a lot depends on what exactly is the structure of two lists and also what have you tried so far

Comment: Impossible to give you a specific answer without any details on the list. Even if you did provide those details, it sounds like you're asking us to do it for you. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq only:

```
bool hasAllItems = UserList.All(s => SystemList.Any(mo => mo.Id == s));
```